# How can I check Lightning component input before proceeding to save?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I have lightning component which uses the values in the input to create a record. I want to add some validation to prevent the record from completing the `save` function if they are not populated or if the characters exceed 50 characters.

How can I do this?

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="NewPersonAccountCont" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

                    <lightning:input label="First Name" aura:id="fName" class="margin-top-50" />
                    <lightning:input label="Last Name" aura:id="lName" class="margin-top-50" />

                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" iconName="utility:save" iconPosition="left" onclick="{! c.save }" class="margin-top-50" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller (JS)

```
...

    save: function(component, event, helper){
        var action = component.get('c.createApplication');

        action.setParams({
            accountId: component.get('v.accountId'),
            fName: component.get('v.fName'),
            lName: component.get('v.lName'),
            cName: component.get('v.cName')
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();

            if(state == 'SUCCESS'){
                var res = response.getReturnValue();

                helper.setMessage(component, res.title, res.type, res.message);

                if(res.recId != null && res.recId != ''){
                    var urlEvent = $A.get('e.force:navigateToURL');
                    urlEvent.setParams({
                        'url': '/' + res.recId
                    });
                    urlEvent.fire();
                }
            } else if(state == 'ERROR'){
                var errors = response.getError();

                if(errors){
                    for(var i in errors)
                        helper.setMessage(component, 'An Error Occurred', 'error', i.message);
                } else {
                    helper.setMessage(component, 'An Unknown Occurred', 'error', null);
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to control both of these validations with simple attributes on the [`<lightning:input>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) tag:

```
<lightning:input maxLength="50" required="true" ... />
```

Comment: All the required flag seems to do is add an asterisk to the field, but doesnt prevent the record from being saved.

Comment: The linked page also has a length section on **`Input Validation`** which will probably fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

Adding further to @adrian's answer. You need to use the `validity` attribute of the input tag to check the textbox is `valid` if not throw an error message and stop proceeding further.

```
<lightning:input name="fname" label="First Name" aura:id="name" class="margin-top-50" required="true" maxLength="50"/>
<lightning:input name="lname" label="Last Name" aura:id="name" class="margin-top-50" required="true" maxLength="50"/>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" iconName="utility:save" iconPosition="left" onclick="{! c.save }" class="margin-top-50" />
```

controller.js:

```
save :  function(comp,event,helper) {
    var isValid = comp.find("name").reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp){
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
    },true);   

    if (isValid) {
        console.log('All good!!')
    }
},
```

For more info on validity check the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) out.